# How to get the path to an artifact in TeamCity?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, artifact

I have my own script that takes an artifact from the build machine and sends it to a channel. I just find an .apk file in a specific directory. Is there a way to get the artifact path or just name from TeamCity?
PS: I heard about the REST API, but there is no need to download the artifact, I’m trying to send it in messenger.

I'm trying to get the path from TeamCity and I'm expect that someone to help me find a proper way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The physical path is returned from  API with where `27356` is your build id:

`http://teamcity:8111/app/rest/builds/id:27356/artifactsDirectory`

Information on the artifacts themselves are from:

`http://teamcity:8111/app/rest/builds/id:27356/artifacts`

this will also return a list of file nodes which have download `href`s

```
<content href="/app/rest/builds/id:27356/artifacts/content/Makefile.bld_log.txt"/>
```

See the [api doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/rest/buildapi.html#getFilesListOfBuild) for more details on other methods.